# Is MGF1 parameter supported by the rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA1 and rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA256 in mobile iOS?

Tags: java, ios, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I am using the Java algorithms RSA_OAEP_SHA1 with MGF1-SHA1 and MGF1-SHA256 to encrypt some small data which then is required to be decrypted by the iOS device.
So I want to know what values of MGF1 parameter are supported by the algorithms rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA1 and rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA256 in mobile iOS?

Also the vice-versa I want to be supported.